# Check if array is present in another array without exact match

Tags: php, arrays

```
$source = ['domain.com', 'subdomain.value.com'];
$str = ['value.com', 'blur.de', 'hey.as'];
```

How to check if any of `$str` is present in `$source`?

I've tried `in_array` or `array_intersect` but both seem to check for **exact** values, so none match.

In this example, it should match as 'value.com' is present in 'subdomain.value.com'.

Comment: you need something more complicated than `in_array` because there is a bit of extra matching work for the substrings. `in_array` and `array_intersect` do only exact matches. Importantly, to find the right solution-- should `"subdomain.value"` (or just `"value"`, or just `"in.va"`) match to `"subdomain.value.com"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace elements in `$source` with elements in `$str` and see how many replacements were made:

```
str_replace($str, '', $source, $count);
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$source = ['domain.com', 'subdomain.value.com', 'hey.as'];
$str = ['value.com', 'blur.de', 'hey.as'];

function any_item_in_array($needles, $haystack) {
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
        if (in_array($needle, $haystack)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$found = any_item_in_array($str, $source);
```